# NG-Repeat only working once angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to ng-repeat some Json but it's only displaying the second dates and not the first, any ideas as to why?

I've done a promise and it's only getting the 2nd dates element of the Json.

I've been outputting it with the promise but only the element with month : 8 in it is being returned so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why.

JSON

```
[{
   "data":{
      "dates":{
         "month":7,
         "year":2014,
         "ind":[
            {
               "fDate":1406979844,
               "tDate":1425296644,
               "id":1,
               "type":"Weekend",
               "price":22
            }
         ]
      },
      "dates":{
         "month":8,
         "year":2014,
         "ind":[
            {
               "fDate":1406979844,
               "tDate":1425296644,
               "id":2,
               "type":"Midweek",
               "price":234
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}]
```

HTML

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="d in dates">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{d.month}} - {{d.year}}</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="ind in d.ind">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ind.fDate}}</td>
                        <td>{{ind.type}}</td>
                        <td>{{ind.price}}</td>
                        <td><a class="colour" href="{{ind.id}}">Book</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error on a jsfiddle or something so we can play?

Answer (score 0):

Your "dates" need to be in an array:

```
[{
   "data":
    [
      {"dates":..},
      {"dates":..}
    ]
}]
```

Otherwise, you have two keys (`dates`) that are named the same in your main JSON object